# Report reuse for PHP projects in Sonarqube 4.2

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, jenkins-php

I have a Jenkins job running for my project that generates reports for the following tools:

- phpcpd
- pdepend
- phpcs
- phpmd
- phpunit (unit & integration tests)

I would like to have Sonar-runner analyze these reports, especially for integration tests, which the runner does not execute.

Is this still possible in Sonar 4.2? If so, what parameters in `sonar-project.properties` controls report re-use for the above listed tools?

I can't find documentation on how to get to sonar-runner to re-use these reports. The only [documented](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PHP+Plugin) parameters seem to be `sonar.php.tests.reportPath` and `sonar.php.tests.coverage.reportPath`. But these only relate to unit tests.

The only information I could find on this is [this blog post](http://cvuorinen.net/2013/07/installing-sonarqube-with-jenkins-integration-for-a-php-project). I've tried the parameters listed there and they appear to have no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed since version 2.0, the SonarQube PHP plugin doesn't rely anymore on external tools like pdepend, phpcs, phpcpd and phpmd. The only remaining external dependency is on phpunit.

Comment: Thanks, that clear things up. Is there a way to analyze integration tests reports generated from phpunit, similar to unit tests?

Comment: Unhappily not, you can only import one unit test execution report.

Comment: Also there's an outstanding issue to allow integration test reports: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPHP-405